# What is the maximum number of bits mining hardware ever needs to hash at one time?

Tags: asic, mining-hardware

What would be the max number of bits that hashing hardware specifically designed for bitcoin mining would ever need to hash per operation?  For example:

block header = 80 bytes = 640 bits
after first hash = 256 bits

To find merkle root:   256(per txn) x 2 = 512 bits

So is 640 bits the max input message size the hashing hardware needs to handle?

Comment: Note that 1. finding the Merkle root only needs to be done once per 4 billion hash attempts. 2. Most of the time just one branch needs to be calclated. 3. The main loop in SHA-256 calculation always works on a 2048-bit message schedule, so the initial message size might not have a great significance on hardware design.

Comment: SHA-256 operates on a 512 bit message block.  So I believe the hashing hardware can compute the initial block header hash with just two blocks.